# Is there a Git API List of Pull Request To Review?

Tags: github, github-api, pull-request

I want to list up my team's pull request list not approved by me

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls#list-pull-requests

I tried that API but it is return full list of my team's PR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and [install the GitHub CLI `gh`](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation), to use [gh pr list](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_list), with a [search term](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/filtering-and-searching-issues-and-pull-requests#about-search-terms):

```
gh pr list --search "state:open type:pr review:approved"
```

Compare it to:

```
gh pr list --search "state:open type:pr"
```

The delta are the PRs you did not approved yet.

Comment: Thanks, but i need API! because i want to use that API at the github actions

Comment: @iamsy As [documented here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/using-github-cli-in-workflows), GitHub CLI is preinstalled on all GitHub-hosted runners: you can use `gh` command directly (which, in turn, calls the GitHub API endpoints).

Comment: is it able to get other user's pr list too?

Comment: @iamsy as [documented](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_list), it can filter by assignee, or by author.